# Full join two tables with three merged columns and some unique columns

Tags: sql, database

Any help on the below would be great, I have been trying for days to get it right.

I have two tables as per the below screenshot:

[image: Join tables]

What I need is to have a new table with single `Period`, `PropertyID` and `TransactionCodeID` columns.

These must be populated with the value columns `BalanceBF`, `BudgetAmount`, `ActualAmount` and `RevisedBudget` from the two tables where any one of them appear in a row in either of the above tables.

So all values from both tables must appear and can be joined into one row where applicable.

I have tried  `FULL OUTER JOIN` and other join types but no luck

Any ideas on how to do this?

If I could append (`coalesce`?) those first three columns then `FULL OUTER JOIN` the two tables value columns would that work? Not sure how to do this.

EDIT:

I'm using the following code:

```
SELECT         
    dbo.PropertyBudgets.Period, 
    dbo.PropertyBudgets.PropertyID, 
    dbo.PropertyBudgets.TransactionCodeID, 
    dbo.AccountBalances.BalanceBf, 
    dbo.PropertyBudgets.BudgetAmount, 
    dbo.PropertyBudgets.ActualAmount, 
    dbo.PropertyBudgets.RevisedBudget
FROM
    dbo.AccountBalances 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.PropertyBudgets ON dbo.AccountBalances.PropertyID = dbo.PropertyBudgets.PropertyID 
                        AND dbo.AccountBalances.TransactionCodeID = dbo.PropertyBudgets.TransactionCodeID 
                        AND dbo.AccountBalances.Period = dbo.PropertyBudgets.Period
WHERE        
    (NOT (dbo.AccountBalances.BalanceBf = 0)) OR
    (NOT (dbo.PropertyBudgets.BudgetAmount = 0)) 
    OR (NOT (dbo.PropertyBudgets.ActualAmount = 0)) 
    OR (NOT (dbo.PropertyBudgets.RevisedBudget =0))`
```

I get the below result output:

[image: Table]

As can be seen  where `BalanceBF` column returns values the others are `NULL` (in the first three columns) I would like these to have the applicable values from the table in the `AccountBalances` table I tried doing this as below:

[image]

So the values in the last three columns in the image below just need to be in the first three columns where `null` appears in the image below:

[image]

Please let me know what is possible.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please see EDIT, hope it clarifies things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved in SSIS by selecting all text columns from both tables, doing a `union all join`, removing duplicates with `aggregate` and then `outer joining` the numeric data columns from both tables to the union table.